# How to generate AsyncResponse-style methods using OpenAPI Generator for jaxrs-spec?

Tags: jax-rs, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I need to generate server-side service interfaces that perform asynchronous processing using the [jaxrs-spec](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/jaxrs-spec.md) generator. I see that the generator supports JAX-RS 2.1 `CompletionStage`-style asynchronous generation out of the box (see `supportAsync`), but it does not seem to support JAX-RS 2.0 `AsyncResponse`-style. Unfortunately, I need to use the `AsyncResponse` style because the web framework I'm using doesn't support the `CompletionStage` approach.

How can I convince the OpenAPI Generator to generate methods this way? I'm using the maven plugin, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving the problem using [template customization](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/). I wrote up the whole process on [GitHub](https://github.com/sigpwned/openapi-generator-maven-plugin-template-customization-example) in case it can be helpful to anyone else. If you want to use the OpenAPI Generator to generate service interfaces with `AsyncResponse`-style asynchronous processing, then that project should work out of the box. If you need to do any other kind of OpenAPI Generator template customization, then that should be a useful example to get started.