# Return StreamingOutput from interface generated by OpenAPI spec using jaxrs-spec generator

Tags: java, jax-rs, openapi-generator

I would like to return a [StreamingOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) when implementing an interface generated from an OpenAPI specification using [jaxrs-spec](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/jaxrs-spec/). The default implementation only uses `java.io.File` as a return value.

We load user-generated data from a DB or even stream it from a different service and would like to avoid having to create a temporary file just to conform with the interface.

The current configuration using the [maven plugin](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/) looks like this

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- <phase/> and <goals/> -->
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>path/to/openapi/spec.yml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>jaxrs-spec</generatorName>
                <configOptions>
                    <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <useSwaggerAnnotations>false</useSwaggerAnnotations>

                    <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>

                    <title>${title}</title>
                    <apiPackage>com.example.api</apiPackage>
                    <modelPackage>com.example.model</modelPackage>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With this setup, I use the following OpenAPI definition

```yaml
/documents/{id}:
  get:
    summary: Get the given document as PDF
    operationId: getDocument
    parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
    responses:
      200:
        description: Get the document
        content:
          application/pdf:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
      302:
        description: Redirect to the location of the PDF document
        headers:
          Location:
            description: The URL from where to get the PDF document
            schema:
              type: string
      404:
        description: Document not found
```

which results in this method

```java
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces({ "application/pdf" })
File getDocument(@PathParam("id") String id)
```

How can I change the return value to something using a stream, e.g. a StreamingOutput? Alternatively, I could also work with a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`.

When I set the `returnResponse` parameter in the generator, this method will return a `Response`, but so will also all other methods generated from this OpenAPI spec and I would need to align all implementations and tests.

I have looked into customizing the templates, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799963), but this feels too much for such a little change.

Comment: At work we've had to use StreamingOutput once. We ended up creating our own generator, based on an existing one. In this case that would be JavaJAXRSSpecServerCodegen. Inside we mapped file to StreamingOutput in typeMapping, and added an entry to importMapping for the import.

Comment: @KJ It makes sense to make this difference when using the term stream as in a continuous time-sensitive transmission of data.

For this question, however, there is no difference in the actual data transferred: both approaches, a file or byte array and a stream provide the exact same data in the same order. The difference lies in the way the data is allocated.

With a byte array, all data has to be available in memory, with a stream, it could be directly streamed from a source without having to load everything into memory.

Comment: @KJ This question concerns how to properly transform the OpenAPI specification to a Java interface that does not required loading the whole file into memory. I am certain, your comments are relevant when optimizing for PDF content. In the context of this question, I do not think, they will help me find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can archive similar result just by using TypeMapping+ImportMapping

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    .. rest of configuration ..
    <typeMappings>
      <typeMapping>binary=OutputStream</typeMapping>
      <typeMapping>file=OutputStream</typeMapping>
    </typeMappings>
    <importMappings>
      <importMapping>OutputStream=my.custom.OutputStream</importMapping>
    </importMappings>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    .. your executions ..       
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is much better. Thank you!

I just replaced `OutputStream` with `StreamingOutput` and `my.custom.OutputStream` with `javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput` and everything works as it should

Answer (score 0):

Following Rob's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940796/return-streamingoutput-from-interface-generated-by-openapi-spec-using-jaxrs-spec#comment132249915_74940796), just a few steps need to be taken when using this via Maven and [openapi-generator-maven-plugin](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/#maven)

1. Create a new maven module.
2. Create a class for the code generator extending [JavaJAXRSSpecServerCodegen](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/v6.2.1/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/JavaJAXRSSpecServerCodegen.java). This adds `"StreamingOutput"` as type mapping for `"file"` and `"binary"` (only `"file"` was sufficient for my spec) and also adds an import for `javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput`

   ```java
   public class JaxrsSpecStreamingOutputGenerator extends JavaJAXRSSpecServerCodegen {

       protected static final String GENERATOR_NAME = "jaxrs-spec-streamingoutput";

       @Override
       public String getName() {
           return GENERATOR_NAME;
       }

       @Override
       public String getHelp() {
           return super.getHelp() + "\njava.io.File is replaced with " + StreamingOutput.class.getName();
       }

       public JaxrsSpecStreamingOutputGenerator() {
           String shortName = "StreamingOutput";

           importMapping.put(shortName, StreamingOutput.class.getName());
           // use 'StreamingOutput' for 'binary' and 'file'
           typeMapping.put("binary", shortName);
           typeMapping.put("file", shortName);
       }
   }
   ```

   This code generator is identified by `jaxrs-spec-streamingoutput`
3. Add `META-INF/services/org.openapitools.codegen.CodegenConfig` with the following contents:

   ```
   ${package}.JaxrsSpecStreamingOutputGenerator
   ```

   (replace `${package}` with the actual package name)

---

Alternatively, the maven module and all necessary files generated using the OpenAPI Generator CLI [meta](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage/#meta) command.

```bash
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-6.2.1.jar \
    meta \
    -o jaxrs-spec-streamingoutput \
    -n jaxrs-spec-streamingoutput \
    -p ${package}
```

(replace `${package}` with the actual package name)

From the generated module, only keep the generator class and the `CodegenConfig` in `META-INF/services`. Adapt the generator class as described in step 2 above.

---

The maven module can then be installed (`mvn install`) and used via the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`. Set `generatorName` and include the maven module as plugin dependency:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
   <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${plugin-version}</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>generate-resources</phase>
         <goals>...</goals>
         <configuration>
            <inputSpec>...</inputSpec>
            <!-- 1. set generator name -->
            <generatorName>jaxrs-spec-streamingoutput</generatorName>
            <configOptions>...</configOptions>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <!-- 
            2. add this module to the dependencies
            e.g. '${project.groupId}:api-codegen:${version}'
         -->
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The `configOptions` can be used as in [`jaxrs-spec` generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/jaxrs-spec/).

Comment: I have added an issue to OpenAPITools/openapi-generator: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14527